# Как конвертировать к наследнику?

Tags: c#

Есть класс со скудным функционалом, но который сильно завязан в чужой инфраструктуре. Класс без конструкторов. От него можно наследоваться.
Но как использовать наследника потом? Приведение типов сделать невозможно.

```
using System;

namespace teST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new FooBase();
            Poo poo = ( Poo ) foo;

            poo.Foo();
        }
    }

    public class FooBase
    {
        public string ToFoo() => "FooBase";
    }

    public class Poo : FooBase
    {


        public void Foo() => Console.WriteLine( ToFoo() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Эээ, ну да, вы создали экземпляр базового класса, приведение типов не вытащит вам из рукава производный класс. Создавайте объект производного класса сразу.

Comment: @VladD, я не могу этого сделать. Логика создания экземпляра скрыта от меня, сам я наполнить класс не могу. Решил спросить у знающих перед реализацией логики в расширениях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что на самом деле тебе нужны extension-методы:

http://ideone.com/VnYNlB

```
using System;

public class FooBase
{
  public string ToFoo() => "FooBase";
}

public static class Poo
{
  public static void Foo(this FooBase foo) => Console.WriteLine(foo.ToFoo());
}

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var foo = new FooBase();
    foo.Foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Не то, что бы нужны. Но видимо по другому никак.